# Spingboot Websocket Stomp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq

Could anyone tell me if the server-side implementation is using stomp WebSocket, is the client also expected to implement stomp?

I am trying to implement a spring boot application and I am confused if I should go with or without stomp implementation. From my research, I understand, if you want to scale the application, it is better to use stomp and embedded broker( RabbitMQ for eg.) as it will handle the sessions, heartbeat etc. instead of an in-memory broker.

The examples available online just shows implementations with and without stomp.

I am basically trying to get different datasets from the table upon client request and write to a WebSocket continuously.

1. Could anyone please confirm if my understanding so far is correct?
2. What are the essential things I will have to take care of if I go with stomp + websocket?

Updating the usecase below:

The mobile client would be displaying charts upon user login. There would be links in the left panel for eg. Sales, Discounts etc. which upon clicking, the request will reach server through websocket channel. Server will check the datatype in the request, generate the model using data from DB and write the data to the websocket.

Updating code - v1
MyWebSocketHandler:

```
@Component
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    DashboardUtil dashboardutil;

    @Resource(name = "socketSessionsMap")
    private Map<String, WebSocketSession> socketSessionsMap;

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        try {
            //Gets the socket session from map and writes a json to that socket - did for testing purpose.
            socketSessionsMap.put("session", session);
            //String payload = message.getPayload();

            String jsonString = dashboardutil.getDataInJSON(); // gets hardcoded json model
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(jsonString));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addHandler(myWebSocketHandler, "/socketHandler").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone tell me if the server-side implementation is using stomp
>   WebSocket, is the client also expected to implement stomp?

You can register multiple handlers in your web socket configuration. So in theory you can provide a handler for STOMP and another one for plain web socket. If you only provide a STOMP handler then the handshake from a standard web socket client will fail.

> From my research, I understand, if you want to scale the application,
>   it is better to use stomp and embedded broker( RabbitMQ for eg.) as it
>   will handle the sessions, heartbeat etc. instead of an in-memory
>   broker.

That's correct. STOMP also offers a few more nice features especially the subscription to certain endpoints.

> I am basically trying to get different datasets from the table upon
>   client request and write to a WebSocket continuously.

That's a really simple description ...
You should think about if you need to share sessions across multiple instances or if you need to send messages between web socket sessions.
From your description it sounds like you just accept a web socket connection and continuously push data to the client. If you want to scale this application you can just put a load balancer in front of your instances and you are good to go.

Comment: I think the client is using basic WS. I'm sure there other things to consider but I don't know what those are. I had mentioned a few concepts I know that are involved in WebSocket communication. Hence, question #2.
I'm yet to look into [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-websocket.html) for handling sessions. To start with, what I need to know is whether I should extend my WebSocketConfig 
 class with WebSocketConfigurer or a WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer or AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session>

Comment: Just to brief you on the use case. The client would be displaying charts upon user login. There would be links in the left panel for eg. Sales, Discounts etc. which upon clicking, the request will reach server through websocket channel. Server will check the datatype in the request, generate the data from DB and write the data to the websocket. Could you please suggest how I should I go about it?

Comment: @continuousLearner If the client is using basic web socket then you should implement a handler for basic web socket in server as well. Otherwise the server won't accept the handshake. So If you can't change the client then you have no other options. Also your use case sounds that basic websocket is fine for your use case.

Comment: Peter - Just confirmed that client implementation is not done yet. Secondly, when you say basic websocket - are you referring to WebSocketConfigurer? Updating question with the code.

Comment: With basic web socket I mean the default protocol. Yes you can use a `WebSocketConfigurer` to register your handler there. If you want to use a sub protocol like STOMP then you have to register STOMP endpoints in your `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`.

Comment: @continuousLearner I would recommend to watch this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxakp15CACY
It is really detailed and shows pros and cons of the protocols and sub protocols.

Comment: Peter, So Sergi Almar recommends using an embedded broker if I want to scale the application. Also, he is using AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<Session> for handling sessions. I guess I was confusing myself by mixing things up. It is either basic WS or STOMP. Doesn't matter what I choose, I can still configure a websocketbroker ( in-memory or embedded). Am I correct?